# ng-repeat working but not showing expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Im fairly new to angular and am having trouble show my scope variables in the expression. It is repeating through the items properly but not showing expressions. I tried ng-bind and other options with no luck. Any help would be great! Thanks

```
//html     
<div >
      <div class="row pad" ng-repeat="boat in boats">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="proimg" src="img/Example.png"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <span class='text-center' >{{boat.title}}</span>
                <ul class="detailList">
                    <li>{{ boat.title }}</li>
                    <li ng-bind="description">{{ boat.description }}</li>
                    <li>{{ boat.price }}</li>    
          </div>
        </div>
    <hr>
 </div>

/js 
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://mysite.firebaseio.com/boats");
    $scope.boats = firebaseRef
```

Comment: console.log($scope.boats) and paste the json obtained here. I think you are not accessing the correct keys

Comment: hmm... its returning undefined

Comment: Exactly. So did you have a look at the JSON that $scope.boats is?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the firebase implementation in wrong way. You should use the ref, which is the root of your firebase db to access its child using appropriate methods. Since firebase works in an async manner, you can pass a callback and access the required data as shown

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://mysite.firebaseio.com/boats");

// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
firebaseRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  $scope.boats = snapshot.val() 
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Refer this for details on retrieving data from firebase: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html.

It is recommended to use `Angular fire` for using firebase with angular as it provides nice wrapper over firebase methods through angular services. Refer https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Comment: thanks! i adjusted it to this and its returning an array of objects, how would I repeat throught them?

Comment: Whats the value of `snapshot.val()` in the console.log?

Comment: Object {-KHGlQwyKfTNdkMkAzPM: Object, -KHGqHi4r2xJKfc_vXiy: Object, -KHGwUJZhzgIvktklljb: Object}

Comment: Can you provide the stringified value instead of this? This is not very useful for debugging

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(snapshot.val())` and provide the returned value