# ng-repeat through items from firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am trying to ngrepeat through items from firebase. I have them in the console.but the expressions are not working. Im not sure what to do and have tried everything. Any help would be great. Thanks

**image of console here:**

[image]

```
//js
firebaseRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.boats = snapshot.val();
        console.log($scope.boats); //image of console up^
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    },0);
});

//html
     <div class="row pad" ng-repeat="boat in boats">
        <span class='text-center' >{{boat.title}}</span>
     </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your HTML content contains the same controller as firebase? Try printing complete content in HTML using `{{boats}}`. If not, then first try to solve that issue.

Comment: @VikramTiwari, I only have one controller but the {{boats}} is not working. either. Any suggestions how I should approach that? Thanks

Comment: Try adding `$scope.$apply()` after you assign a value to boats.

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-arrays

Comment: @clint, Once I add  apply the {{boats}} display but expressions like {{boat.title}} still dont work

Comment: @VikramTiwari, I got the {{boats}} to work

Comment: @KielL. I'm at a bit of a loss, what does {{boats}} print?

Comment: If `{{boats}}` is working then you just need to wrap your `ng-repeat` in the same DOM tree as `{{boats}}`` is

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. Also: please don't delete your previous question and post a new one with the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat working but not showing expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104893/ng-repeat-working-but-not-showing-expression)

Answer (score 3):

The data is stored as `boat.Title` but is being accessed as `boat.title`

Answer (score 2):

@funador is correct, you need `boat.Title` instead of `boat.title`.

However, you should look into using **[AngularFire for Angular 1](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/)** to make your life a bit easier.

AngularFire synchronizes collections with the Firebase database and the `$digest` loop.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController)
  .config(function($firebaseRefProvider, FirebaseUrl) {
     $firebaseRefProvider.registerUrl({
       default: FirebaseUrl,
       boats: FirebaseUrl + '/boats'
     });
  });

function MyController($scope, $firebaseRef, $firebaseArray) {
  $scope.boats = $firebaseArray($firebaseRef.boats);
}
```

AngularFire allows you to specify your references in the `config` phase using the `$firebaseRefProvider`. Then you'll be able to inject the `$firebaseRef` service.

A `$firebaseArray` will automatically synchronize changes to your template. To create one, pass in `boats` the reference to the array.

What's awesome about this is that there's no `$timeout` needed. AngularFire handles it for you.

And your `ng-repeat` is still the same:

```
<div class="row pad" ng-repeat="boat in boats">
  <span class='text-center' >{{boat.title}}</span>
</div>
```